# Functions with arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I'm taking this programming class and one of our assignments is to make a quiz and return right and wrong answers. So I've coded it all and the only thing that seems to be wrong is my passing of arguments. My result is always zero I'd appreciate any help given.

Here is my code:

```
correctAnswers = 0
wrongAnswers = 0

answer = input("Question 1: 5-3")
if(answer == 2):
    correctAnswers + 1
else:
    wrongAnswers +1

grade(correctAnswers, wrongAnswers)

grade(right, wrong):
    right - wrong
    print("You have a total of " + str(right) + " correct answers")
```

It's just a snippet of it, but gets the idea across.

Comment: This code never assigns a value back to `correctAnswers` or `wrongAnswers` nor stores the value that `right - wrong` evaluates to.

Comment: What is `right - wrong` supposed to do? You're doing subtraction, but not saving the result anywhere.

Comment: It seems like you were asleep on the day the class studied assigning variables.

Comment: @MattBall  This is just a snippet of the full code.

Comment: Then you need to provide a **complete** example that reproduces the exact problem you're facing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MattBall I'm sorry about that. I just didn't want to 1) Make my post too long. 2) feel like I'm cheating in my class, because I enjoy programming and want to learn more than just get an answer.

Comment: a minimal example is never too long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a string to and int:

```
  int(input("Question 1: 5-3")) # cast to int
```

You also need `+=` not just `+` `correctAnswers += 1`

You may also have meant to `print(right - wrong)`?

Instead of casting you can also compare to a string:`if answer == "2"`

`"foo"+ "bar"` will indeed create a new object but that is concatenation, but when you want to increment a variable you need to use `+=` which is short form for `var = var + 1`.

lastly when casting a string to an int, to make sure the user enters valid data using a while loop which will keep asking until the user enters data that  can be cast to an int and using a try/except to catch bad input would be a good idea:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("Question 1: 5-3"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
if answer == 2:
    correctAnswers += 1
else:
    wrongAnswers += 1
```

Comment: @Christopherm have you used `+=` also?

Comment: I'm going to do that now. Thank you

Comment: It worked! Would you mind explaining how that makes it work compared to just the + rather than +=?

Comment: @Christopher, added an example to bottom of my answer

Comment: @Christopher, you need to assign your value somewhere. `correctAnswers  += 1` is shorthand for: `correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1`. It is not uncommon to misunderstand the idea of assigning values. `correctAnswers + 1` does return a value, but that value needs to get assigned somewhere, otherwise it will not be used. Open a python terminal and type `1 + 1` what do you get? 2, but that value is not assigned to a variable.